# I am not able to install apache2

Tags: apt, apache2, lamp

I am trying to install `apache2` by using `sudo apt install apache2`.
I am getting error :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apache2 : Depends: apache2-utils (= 2.4.52-1ubuntu4.1)
 apache2-bin : Depends: libapr1 (>= 1.7.0) but it is not installable
               Depends: libaprutil1 (>= 1.6.0) but it is not installable
               Depends: libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 but it is not installable or
                        libaprutil1-dbd-mysql but it is not installable or
                        libaprutil1-dbd-odbc but it is not installable or
                        libaprutil1-dbd-pgsql but it is not installable or
                        libaprutil1-dbd-freetds but it is not installable
               Depends: libaprutil1-ldap but it is not installable
               Depends: liblua5.3-0 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I am using **Kubuntu 22.04**

#### Edit :

I am also NOT able to install `mysql-server`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages). The system should be up-to-date and the package manager should not have any problems before you attempt to install any new software.

Comment: The problem was already resolved after I did a restart. Thanks for your valuable time here !